# Web report table error unknown cause

Tags: php, mysql

So im currently testing my web report table. So on initial testing there's no error and the table would look like this, same as i design it
[Table report default design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy18n.jpg)

but after hooking it on with the hardware and stuff i found that the table sometimes become like this [problem table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kGmB.jpg)

after restarting the program then the table become normal again. this problem occur sometimes and no frequently. What could cause this to happened?

Here's the php codes

```
<?php require_once('Connections/sizeCount.php'); ?>
<?php
$to = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day".$_GET['to']));
mysql_select_db($database_sizeCount, $sizeCount);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM temp_frm_mngmt_tbl";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $sizeCount) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) 
{
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

        $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Daily Former Management Report</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <style>
        @page {size 8.5in 11in;}
        div.page { page-break-after: always}  <!-- break after printing -->
        <!-- type="text/css" media="print">.breakAfter{ -->
    </style>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<thead>
</thead>

<body> <!-- Body1 as Page Header -->
    <div align="center">
    <?php
        #$mnthName =  $_GET['mnthName'];
        #$year =  $_GET['year'];
        $SelectedDate =  $_GET['from'];

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        $date = date('d M Y', time() + $timezone);
        $time = date('h:i:s A', time() + $timezone);

        $PageFormat = '<table width="900" border="1" align="center" rules="all" class="graypanel">';
        $TableHeaderStyle="<td style='text-align:center;face:Times New Roman;font-size:20;'>";
        $TableStyleLeft="<td style='text-align:left;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5;'>";
        $TableStyleRight="<td style='text-align:right;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5;'>";
        $TableStyleCenter="<td style='text-align:center;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5;'>";
        $TableStyleSubTotal="<td style='text-align:right;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5; background-color:#bebaa7;'>";
        $TableStyleSubTotal="<td style='text-align:right;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5;font-weight:bold;'>";
        $TableStyleSubTotalCenter="<td style='text-align:center;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5; background-color:#bebaa7;'>";
        #$TableStyleSubTotal="<td style='text-align:right;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5;font-weight:bold;background-color:#bebaa7;'>";
        $TableStyleSubTotalLeft="<td style='text-align:left;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5;font-weight:bold;'>";
        $TableStyleSubTotalRight="<td colspan = 2 style='text-align:center; face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5;font-weight:bold;'>";
        #$TableStyleSubTotalLeft="<td style='text-align:left;face:Times New Roman;font-size:10.5; background-color:#bebaa7;'>";

        #$PageHeader1 = '<p align="center"><strong>Perusahaan Getah Asas Sdn Bhd (P2A)</strong><br>';
        #$PageHeader1 = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Report Generated: '.$date. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;". $time;
        #$PageHeader2 = "<strong>Cummulative Glove Size Counting System</strong></p> <p> Line : ".$_GET['line']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Side : ".$_GET['side']."</p>";

        $PageHeader1 = '<strong style ="font-size:18px";>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Daily Former Management Report </strong><strong style ="font-size:10.5px";>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Report Date: '.$date. "&nbsp;". $time.'</strong>';                              
        $PageHeader2 = '<p align="center" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style4">Plant</span> </strong><strong><span class="style4">P2A - All Lines</strong></p>';
        $PageHeader3 = '<p align="left" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Former Management by Line</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Day: '.$SelectedDate.'</strong></p>';
        #$PageHeader1 = '<div width="900" align="left" rules="all"><strong style ="font-size:18px";><span style="float:center;">Daily Glove Production Performance Report</span></strong><strong style ="font-size:10.5px";><span style="float:right;">Report Date: '.$date. "&nbsp;". $time.'</span></strong></div>';


        $TableHeader = '                    
                    <tr><bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
                    <th colspan = "1" width="40px" align="center"> </th>
                    <th colspan = "17" width="70px" align="center">Former Installation </th>                    
                    </tr>

                    <tr><bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
                    <th colspan = "1" width="40px" align="center"> </th>
                    <th colspan = "1" width="40px" align="center"> </th>
                    <th colspan = "2" width="40px" align="center">Size XS</th>
                    <th colspan = "2" width="40px" align="center">Size S</th>
                    <th colspan = "2" width="40px" align="center">Size M</th>
                    <th colspan = "2" width="40px" align="center">Size L</th>
                    <th colspan = "2" width="40px" align="center">Size XL</th>
                    <th colspan = "2" width="40px" align="center">Size XXL</th>
                    <th colspan = "4" width="40px" align="center">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
                    <th width="70px" align="center">Line</th>
                    <th width="70px" align="center">Side</th>
                    <th width="77px" align="center">Shrtg (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Instld (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="77px" align="center">Shrtg (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Instld (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="77px" align="center">Shrtg (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Instld (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="77px" align="center">Shrtg (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Instld (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="77px" align="center">Shrtg (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Instld (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="77px" align="center">Shrtg (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Instld (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="77px" align="center">Shrtg (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Shrtg (%)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Instld (pcs)</th>
                    <th width="78px" align="center">Max. (pcs)</th>                                                            
                    </tr>'; 
    echo '<tbody>';
        $i = 0;
        echo $PageFormat;   # $PageFormat must be included here
        $PrevLine = "";
        $CurrLine = "";

        do
        {
                if (($i % 30) == 0)
                {               
                    if ($i > 0)
                    {
            echo '</td></tr></table>'.$PageFormat;  # $PageFormat must be included here
                        echo '<div class="page"></div>';  # leave blank for text inside div
                    }

                    echo $PageHeader1;
                    echo $PageHeader2;
                    echo $PageHeader3;
                    //echo $TableHeaderStyle; 
                    echo $TableHeader; echo '</td>';                    
                }

                $TestStr1 = $row_Recordset1['LineDayMonth'];
                $TestStr2 = "Total";                            

                $CurrLine = $row_Recordset1['LineDayMonth'];
                    if($CurrLine == $PrevLine)
                    {
                        $CurrLine = "";
                    }
                    if($CurrLine == 'Total')
                    {
                        $CurrLine = $row_Recordset1['LineDayMonth'];

                    }

$shrtg_Perc = $row_Recordset1['Shrtg_Perc'];

if($shrtg_Perc == null)
{
    $shrtg_Perc = 0;

}



                echo '<tr>';
                if($TestStr1 == $TestStr2) {
          echo $TableStyleSubTotalRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".$CurrLine."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

                        echo "&nbsp;".$row_Recordset1['Side']; echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_XS']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_XS']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_S']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_S']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_M']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".$row_Recordset1['Instl_M']; echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_L']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_L']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_XL']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_XL']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_XXL']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_XXL']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_Total']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".$shrtg_Perc; echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_Total']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleSubTotal;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['MaxPcs']); echo '</td>';
                    }
                    else {
                    echo $TableStyleCenter;
                        echo "&nbsp;".$CurrLine."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    echo $TableStyleCenter;
                        echo "&nbsp;".$row_Recordset1['Side']; echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_XS']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_XS']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_S']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_S']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_M']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_M']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_L']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_L']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_XL']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_XL']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_XXL']); echo '</td>';
                    echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_XXL']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Shrtg_Total']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".$shrtg_Perc; echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['Instl_Total']); echo '</td>';
          echo $TableStyleRight;
                        echo "&nbsp;".number_format ($row_Recordset1['MaxPcs']); echo '</td>';
                    }
                    $PrevLine = $row_Recordset1['LineDayMonth'];
                    echo'</tr>';
            ++$i;
        } while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
    echo '</tbody>';
    ?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please kindly outline what the problem in the problem table is for those of us where the problem is not immediately apparent, thank you kindly.

Comment: Ohhh my apologies, the problem table, the table isnt arrange accoding to its numbering for example it should be L1,L2,L3 not L4,L6,L1 in the problem table

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, Could you please show us how you are sorting the table?

Comment: If you mean in codes i will show you. But if you wanna see how it supposed to look like you can refer to the table report default design to see how the table should look like

Comment: Ahh sorry, I meant to say could you please show us how you are sorting the table in the code?

Comment: I already edited the question and include the php codes